# Deleted .aae files and my photos are gone, how to restore, Help Please

Tags: iphone, file-recovery

I deleted .aae files by mistake and all of my related photos are gone. How do I recover these missing photos?

iPhone 6, iOS 9.2.1

Comment: @grg well technically, this was asked before so this isn't the duplicate, the other question is.

Answer (score 0):

Download another Photo Editor from the iTunes store.  Open it and give it access to your photos.  It will recognize the unedited photos that were seemingly not there before.  This worked when I did the same thing to my .aae files.

Comment: Dedwood, could you please suggest one to download and will this recover the aae files from Recently Deleted on the iPhone? Or does this only work if they were backed up to iTunes first? Thanks.